# Count the number of each letter in a vector of strings

Tags: r

I want to produce a vector which has the total number of each of all 26 numbers from the alphabet that are present in vector `a`.

```
a <- c("aabead", "dadfhhsa")
```

E.g., a in this vector would be equal to 5, b to 1, d to 2, z to 0, x to 0, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do in such this way using `letters` R built-in vector

```
 > sapply(letters, function(x) x<-sum(x==unlist(strsplit(a,""))))
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
5 1 0 3 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 10):

You just need the functions `table` and `strsplit`, with some help from `unlist`:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(a, ""), use.names=FALSE))
#
# a b d e f h s 
# 5 1 3 1 1 2 1
```

- `strsplit` "explodes" the strings into the individual letters. It creates a `list`, one item for each string in your vector "a".
- Since the output of `strsplit` is a `list`, you need to `unlist` it before you can tabulate it. The `use.names = FALSE` just gives `unlist` a speed boost.
- `table`, as you've probably guessed by now, tabulates the output.

If you really wanted zero values, you need to stick a `factor` in there too, with some help from the in-built `letters` constant:

```
table(factor(unlist(strsplit(a, ""), use.names=FALSE), levels=letters))
#
# a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
# 5 1 0 3 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

#### Update

When working with these types of problems, where you have to iterate across a significant number of values, it is important to consider how you approach the problem.

In the accepted answer, for example, `unlist(strsplit(...))` is being called 26 times: once for each letter. You would find significant performance improvement by splitting and unlisting the values first, and then using `sapply`. Compare the difference in performance of `fun1a` and `fun2a` below.

For reference, I've also benchmarked my `factor`-based solution along with an alternative using `tabulate`. As can be seen, these are much faster than looping through the individual letters with `sapply`.

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(1)
n <- 100000
a <- stri_rand_strings(n, sample(10, n, TRUE), "[a-z]")

fun1a <- function() sapply(letters, function(x) x<-sum(x==unlist(strsplit(a,""))))
fun1b <- function() {
  temp <- unlist(strsplit(a, ""))
  sapply(letters, function(x) {
    sum(x == temp)
  })
}
fun2 <- function() table(factor(unlist(strsplit(a, "", TRUE), use.names=FALSE), levels=letters))
fun3 <- function() {
  `names<-`(tabulate(
    factor(unlist(strsplit(a, "", TRUE), use.names = FALSE), 
           letters), nbins = 26), letters)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1a(), fun1b(), fun2(), fun3(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  fun1a() 1025.45449 1177.90226 1189.49551 1190.11137 1238.66071 1352.05645    10
#  fun1b()  102.94881  114.08700  115.14852  115.87184  119.06776  124.64735    10
#   fun2()   53.46341   58.67832   67.50402   68.94933   70.71005   95.10771    10
#   fun3()   46.65357   49.79365   51.68536   51.55922   54.36390   57.07582    10
```