# Create a vector of counts

Tags: r

I wanted to create a vector of counts if possible.
For example: I have a vector

`x <- c(3, 0, 2, 0, 0)`

How can I create a frequency vector for all integers between 0 and 3? Ideally I wanted to get a vector like this:

`> 3 0 1 1`

which gives me the counts of 0, 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create the frequency count from a vector in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869374/create-the-frequency-count-from-a-vector-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting the number of each letter in a vector of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476210/counting-the-number-of-each-letter-in-a-vector-of-strings)

Comment: This is a duplicate, but above 2 links are not the right ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
table(factor(x, levels=0:3))
```

Simply using `table(x)` is not enough.

Or with `tabulate` which is faster

```
tabulate(factor(x, levels = min(x):max(x)))
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me an error, Error in factor(gaps, labels = 0:3) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 3

Comment: Maybe a bit "robuster" way would be `r <- range(x) ; table(factor(x, levels = r[1]:r[2]))`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use table():

```
a <- table(x)
a
x
#0 2 3 
#3 1 1
```

Then you can subset it:

```
a[names(a)==0]
#0 
#3
```

Or convert it into a `data.frame` if you're more comfortable working with that:

```
u<-as.data.frame(table(x))
u
#  x Freq
#1 0 3
#2 2 1
#3 3 1
```

Edit 1: 
For levels:

```
a<- as.data.frame(table(factor(x, levels=0:3)))
```

Comment: You are missing a level. See the other answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `rle` (I made this in minutes, so sorry if it's not optimized enough).

```
x = c(3, 0, 2, 0, 0)
r = rle(x)
f = function(x) sum(r$lengths[r$values == x])
s = sapply(FUN = f, X = as.list(0:3))
data.frame(x = 0:3, freq = s)
#> data.frame(x = 0:3, freq = s)
#  x freq
#1 0    3
#2 1    0
#3 2    1
#4 3    1
```